# How to add scrollbars to vue and vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, overflow

I started with vuetify, but scrolling confuse me a lot. I added different sections and try to make it scrollable independent of each other. But either all sections are scrollable with one scrollbar or no section is scrollable.
[Divisions of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq0ib.png)

How can I make the green section scrollable? How can I make the green and the red section scrollable independent of each other?

Here is the App.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar
      app
      color="primary"
      dark
    >
    My Toolbar
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main class="overflow-hidden">
      <v-row class="fill-height">
        <v-col grow class="text-center red overflow-hidden">
           <p>Section 1, not srollable</p>
        </v-col>
        <v-col grow class="d-flex flex-column overflow-hidden grey">
          <div class="text-center yellow overflow-hidden">
           <p>Section 2, not scrollable</p>
          </div>
          <div grow class="text-center green flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-0 overflow-auto">
            <div>
            <p>Section 2, scrollable</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center blue overflow-hidden">
           <p>Section 4, not scrollable</p>
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    //
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>

<style>
html{
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS property that allows us to scroll vertically inside a defined element.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Try adding `overflow-y` to the element you want to scroll.

For instance, if you only want a certain section to be scrollable, you can create a custom css class and add the `overflow-y` property inside of it, and add this class to the elements you want to scroll.

e.g:

```
.scrollable {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And add that class to your div!

```
<div class="scrollable text-center green flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-0 overflow-auto">
   <div>
       <p>Section 2, scrollable</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is exactly the question. It doesn't work. Wether I take the vuetify helpers (overflow-auto, overflow-y-scroll,...) nor I add it as custom css class. Always the same behaviour. Either all sections are scrollable or none.